# Recieved memory warning issue in webview add inside UIScrollview?

Tags: ipad, memory-management, uiwebview, uiscrollview, nsmutablearray

I have tried to load 40 UIWebview in uiscrollview. user scroll more than 5. Recieved memory warning alert comes continuously, finally application quit.
How to manage this memory issue, please let me know.
Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

Description: Load one by one webview are added in UIScrollview because i have tried to load all webview using for loop single time but app crash in this  for loop so doing add one by one process.

```
CGRect vFrame = self.view.frame;
    UIWebView *wViewLocal = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(vFrame.origin.x, vFrame.origin.y, vFrame.size.width, 900)];
    wViewLocal.delegate = self;
    wViewLocal.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    NSString *fileUrl = [[subSubChap objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".htm" withString:@""];
    [wViewLocal fileUrl baseURL:nil];
    [wViewLocal setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [wViewLocal setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [wViewLocal setFrame:CGRectMake(selectedIndex*viewRect.size.width,0,768, 900)]; // here set X-Value each webview.
    [wViewLocal setTag:selectedIndex];
    [scroll_View addSubview:wViewLocal]; // Here i have add UIWebview 
    [self.array_MainObject addObject:wViewLocal]; // Here i have add all UIWebview in NSMutableArray for get particular webview info.
    [wViewLocal release];
```

Comment: 40 webviews at once? Why you not use tableview :|

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but scroll in horizontally so

Comment: Amm.. If I'm getting it right, you want to show 40 web views side by side and the user can swipe to see them? 
Is the user supposed to see one web view at once or he can stop in between as he can see half of the two web views?

Comment: I am not solving your problem but just a suggestion, if you're targetting iOS 6 or greater, you should try UIPageViewController with curl style `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`. Its tailormade for such situations.